# Wildcard / regexp in a phrase which has space

Tags: elasticsearch

Create an index:
Here I an using edge_ngram

```
PUT my_index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 3,
          "max_gram": 3,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "properties": {
        "city": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "fields": {
            "raw": { 
              "type":  "text",
              "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

}





 POST my_index/my_type/1
    {
      "text": "2 #Quick Foxes lived and died"
    }

    POST my_index/my_type/2
        {
          "text": "2 #Quick Foxes lived died"
        }
```

Now when we search

```
GET my_index/my_type/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_operator" : "AND",
       "query" : "f* d*",
      "fields": ["text.raw"]
    }
  }
}
```

Only ID 2 should list. But nothing returns.

when you try this

```
GET my_index/my_type/_search
{
 "query": {
   "query_string": {
     "default_operator" : "AND",
      "query" : "f* d*",
     "fields": ["text"]
   }
 }
}
```

It will return both.

If we have an index with huge data and if we wanted to search wildcards, how we will do it?

single keyword will work, but if we add phrases like which i mentioned in the example, it won't give you any proper result.

Comment: Why should only the second return? Your search says: "I want an 'f' in it, then anything in any number than a scpace, then a 'd' then anything you want'. This matches both. If you wanted only the first, then you should search "f* and d*" if you wanted just the second you need to exclude the "and".

Answer (score 0):

To generate a regex expression you can follow these websites:-

Generate regex expression here- http://buildregex.com/

and test your string with expression generated from here https://regex101.com/

Comment: It it not about generating regex. It is about make it work in ES. I think my question is different